# How R automatically coerces character input to numeric?

Tags: r, character, numeric, coerce

I am training a random forest model in the `randomForest` package for my data. Some variables are in the class of character. I am pretty sure that `randomForest` will only take factor and numeric classes as input. So I think R automatically coerces the character into numeric.

In order for me to know how this may affect my modelling result, does anyone know how R automatically coerces the character into numeric class (like an algorithm/rule)? Or any source code I can look at?

I am using R version 4.0.1.

Thanks in advance.

**An update:**
I checked using

```
getTree(mod,1,labelVar=TRUE)
```

And I can see that if those character variables are converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is an integer (which means it is a categorical variable (see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/getTree)). But if not converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is not integer.

So I guess is that R coerces the values of those character variables into numeric values? But how?

Comment: I think, they are taken as the dummy variables (one hot encoding). One and zeros in other words.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure right now regarding the random forests in R, but I am kind of convinced, that it *only* takes `factor`s. If it does take `character`s as well, it will convert them to factor, not to numeric.

And there is no clear conversion from character to numeric in R.

Comment: I guess your conclusion that it inly takes factors is not correct. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186926/how-randomforest-package-in-r-interprets-character-variables

Comment: I checked using 

    `getTree(mod,1,labelVar=TRUE)`

And I can see that if those character variables are converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is an integer (which means it is a categorical variable (see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/getTree)). But if not converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is not integer. 

So I guess is that R coerces the values of those character variables into numeric values? But how?

Comment: Again, a guess: factors are basically integer vectors where each level corresponds to a `level`. So, my guess is if you have a character vector `c("1", "2", "3", "1")` but the levels are `c("3", "2", "1")` then the integers resulting from the factor vector would be `c(3, 2, 1, 3)`. Check the levels of the factor your dealing with (`levels(your_vector)`) - maybe it helps.