# how randomForest package in R interprets character variables

Tags: r, character-encoding, random-forest

This post is correlated with: [How R automatically coerces character input to numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635535/how-r-automatically-coerces-character-input-to-numeric)

I am a user of the `randomForest` package. I just have a quick question: Can anyone let me know or refer me to the somewhere in the source code that how the `randomForest` package in R takes/treats character variables? I have used character variables as direct input and I also converted the character variables to factors as input, but the performances are different.

Hope for a quick answer or a reference to somewhere in the source code to my problem.

I am using R 4.0.1., and as far I know, an earlier version of R, when you use `randomForest` package, it won't take character variables and will turn an error.

Thank you very much!!

Edit: here is part of the code: The difference is shown in the MAE and MAPE measurement part and the cause of the difference is if I use `as.factor` for the character features. (not shown here)

```
rf <- randomForest(
volume ~ .,
data = master_train,
ntree = 500,
mtry = 15,
nodesize = 50,
maxnodes = 100,
#sampsize = 10000
#replace=T,
#nPerm = 5
importance = T,
#proximity=TRUE,
#keep.forest=FALSE
)

pred1 = predict(rf, newdata = master_train)
pred2 = predict(rf, newdata = master_test)

pred1 = predict(rf, newdata = master_train)
pred2 = predict(rf, newdata = master_test)

pred1[is.na(pred1)] <- 0
pred2[is.na(pred2)] <- 0

mean(abs(pred1 - master_train$volume))
mean(abs(pred2 - master_test$volume))

mean(abs(pred1 - master_train$volume))/mean(master_train$volume)
mean(abs(pred2 - master_test$volume))/mean(master_test$volume)
```

An update: I checked using

```
getTree(mod,1,labelVar=TRUE)
```

And I can see that if those character variables are converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is an integer (which means it is a categorical variable (see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/getTree)). But if not converted to factors, then the "split point" in the output is not integer.

So I guess is that R coerces the values of those character variables into numeric values? But how? -- then it is the topic in the another thread I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: Please, could you post a reproducible example that shows the different performances? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcoSandri it is just calculating the measurement, such as MAE, MAPE from the output (prediction) compared with groundtruth -- I edited my post